# Azure Log Analytics vs Azure Data Factory Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-metrics-advisor

I'd like to see the differences between those two solutions.
I need to store and analyze ADF metadata and SQL Database metadata.
Like pipeline errors, pipeline duration, pipeline parameters, sql table inserted, deleted records.

I'm testing Log Analytics and have some questions:

**Azure Data Factory Analytics/Azure SQL Database Analytics.**

1. Are they just ready charts based on Log Analytics?
2. Is that mean that they are free and there are only costs for Log Analytics?
3. Am I able to create the same charts based on Log Analytics without ADF Analytics and SQL
   Analytics?

**Log Analytics:**

1. How many days data logs are available there? How I can check it?
2. In which way I can store logs and have an access after that period? If I will archive them in
   the storage account can I make queries on them in the Azure Monitor?
3. There are a lot of sample kusto queries to monitor for example errors in the SQL database.
   They are based on table AzureMetrics but I don't have access to it. Do you know how to add it?
4. What's the difference between sending logs to Log Analytics to AzureDiagnostic and ResourceSpecific?
5. If you know about some interesting articles/best practices to store Azure metadata (ADF,
   Databrick, SQL Managed Instance) it will be great if you can post it.

Thanks in advance.